# Redeclaring enumeration

Tags: c#, enums

I am currently have grid with captions and column names filled in from enumeration.

```
private enum enumCaptions
{
    [Description("Status")]
    Active,
    [Description("Part number")]
    Part,
    [Description("Level")]
    Change,
    [Description("Project")]
    Program,
    [Description("Location")]
    Location
}
```

Function that allowing me to read Description, based on value selected

```
public class classStatics
{

    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        //method to read description of the enumeration
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And method that doing just that, looping through my enumeration and assigning captions and names to columns

```
private void fillGridCaptions()
{
    int i = 1;

    grdMy.Cols.Count = Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumCaptions)).Length + 1;

    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(enumCaptions)))
    {

        //assign name for every column from enum
        grdMy.Cols[i].Name = Enum.GetName(typeof(enumCaptions), value);
        //assign caption for every column
        grdMy[0, i] = classStatics.GetEnumDescription((enumCaptions)value).ToString();

        i++;
    }
}
```

Since I have a few grids, but they all should have different data and captions, I would like to create generic function that will take any grid name, any enumeration and assign descriptions to grid captions.
But part where I getting description is not working anymore, enum captionsEnumis not recognized as Enum anymore, however Name values returned properly.

```
private void gridCaptions(FlexGrid gridName, Enum captionsEnum)
{
    int i = 1;
    gridName.Cols.Count = Enum.GetValues(captionsEnum.GetType()).Length + 1;
    foreach (int value in Enum.GetValues(captionsEnum.GetType()))
    {
        gridName.Cols[i].Name = Enum.GetName(captionsEnum.GetType(), value);
        //assign caption for every column

        gridName[0, i] = classStatics.GetEnumDescription(captionsEnum);
        i++;
    }
}
private void fillGridCaptions()
{
    gridCaptionsgrdMy, new enumCaptions());
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have modified your code a bit. I modified the following lines:

- In the for loop, the `value` is changed from `int` to `object`, storing not a number, but the actual item from the enum.
- anyGrid.Cols[i].Name is now assigned directly with the string representation of the enum item.
- anyGrid[0, i] still assigned with description. The function can be called because of the cast to an `Enum`. This was not possible when it was an `int`, because the type of the enum was not known in the generic situation.

The code:

```
private void gridCaptions(FlexGrid anyGrid, Enum anyEnum)
{
        int i = 1;
        anyGrid.Cols.Count = Enum.GetValues(anyEnum.GetType()).Length + 1;
        foreach (object value in Enum.GetValues(anyEnum.GetType()))
        {
            anyGrid.Cols[i].Name = value.ToString();
            anyGrid[0, i] = classStatics.GetEnumDescription((Enum)value);
            i++;
        }
}
```

Comment: This does what his original fillGridCaptions did. I think the point of gridCaptions was to enable him to pass in the enum flags that he wants to use in the columns.

Comment: @MisterXero: I renamed some of my parameters into more generic names. Note: these were only names, not data types. Now it gives a better impression of what my answer actually does.

Comment: Doesn't his original method gridCaptions do the same thing as this?